# Retrieve data from asset database

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Im trying to get the information using 2 tables, but the retrieve info is always came from the comm_stp. How can I manage to get the info from multiple tables respectively?

```
public Cursor getData() {  

    String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;  
    db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,  
    SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);  
    onUpgrade(db, DB_Version, 4);

    Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM comm_filems, comm_stp", null);  
    return c;  
}
```

Comment: Don't you need to write two separate queries for two assets?

Comment: ideally it should work, how did you confirm that you are not getting the columns of comm_files? Please note that you will get cross join result. (And I wonder why you are calling onUpgrade - may be you also need to learn about android DatabaseHelper upgrade mechanism)